# How to remove first line from a text file with cmd?

Tags: batch-file, text, command-line, cmd

This is my text file and I want to remove first line (with blank):

```
abc!
def  #
ghi./;
jklm
nopqrs
```

How can I remove first line from my text file?

I want my second line be first line:

```
def  #
ghi./;
jklm
nopqrs
```

I tried `findstr` command, but it doesn't work.

Comment: note sure why people down-vote it, but I think this is a good question, and the answers are good too.

Comment: Yeah, but it seems like he is looking for a Windows solution. Most solutions here are for linux cli. haven't found a good way on Windows yet for this :(

Answer (score 12):

The easiest approach (assuming your text file is called `data.txt`):

```cmd
more +1 "data.txt" > "data_NEW.txt"
```

This limits lines to a length of about 65535 bytes/characters and the file to about 65535 lines. Furthermore, <kbd>TABs</kbd> become expanded to <kbd>SPACEs</kbd> (8 by default).

---

You could use a `for /F` loop instead (the odd-looking unquoted option string syntax is needed here in order to disable the default `eol` character `;` to not ignore lines beginning with such):

```cmd
@echo off
(
    for /F usebackq^ skip^=1^ delims^=^ eol^= %%L in ("data.txt") do echo(%%L
) > "data_NEW.txt"
```

This limits lines to a length of about 8190 characters/bytes and loses empty lines.

---

You could use a `for /F` loop together with `findstr` to keep empty lines (`findstr` adds a line number plus `:` to each line, so `for /F` does not see empty lines; everything up to the (first) colon is then removed in the loop body; toggling delayed expansion ensures not to lose `!`):

```cmd
@echo off
(
    for /F "skip=1 delims=" %%L in ('findstr /N "^" "data.txt"') do (
        set "LINE=%%L"
        setlocal EnableDelayedExpansion
        echo(!LINE:*:=!
        endlocal
    )
) > "data_NEW.txt"
```

This still limits lines to a length of about 8190 characters/bytes.

---

Or you could use input redirection `<` together with `set /P` (for this the total number of lines needs to be determined in advance):

```cmd
@echo off
for /F %%C in ('find /C /V "" ^< "data.txt"') do set "COUNT=%%C"
setlocal EnableDelayedExpansion
(
    for /L %%I in (1,1,%COUNT%) do (
        set "LINE=" & set /P LINE=""
        if %%I gtr 1 echo(!LINE!
    )
) < "data.txt" > "data_NEW.txt"
endlocal
```

This limits lines to a length of about 1022 characters/bytes.

---

To replace your original file with the modified one, simply do this:

```cmd
move /Y "data_NEW.txt" "data.txt" > nul
```

Comment: Reminds me of the days I used `more` on a regular base on windows, I never really use it these days... thumbs up for that one :)

Comment: Thank you, @GerhardBarnard! Your comment also reminded me that I forgot to mention another limitation that comes up using `more` -- see my edit...

Answer (score 1):

From the prompt,

```
for /f "skip=1delims=" %a in (yourtextfilename) do >>anoutputfilename echo %a
```

where `yourtextfilename` & `anoutputfilename` must be different filenames and need to be "quoted" if they contain spaces or other separators.

Comment: This works for the sample data in the question, however, if the sample data has spaces in each line, this answer does not work. Strictly speak, this answer does not work either, there is a typo here. The correct answer should be `do @echo %a >> anooutputfilename` instead of putting `echo %a` at the very end.

Comment: @jyao : please provide sample data for where this fails. I have tried it using spaces in each line and it worked perfectly. If you mean empty lines or lines that contain *only* spaces, then yes, empty lines will be eliminated (characteristic of `for /f`) and lines containing only spaces will be replaced by `ECHO is on.` (characteristic of `echo`). Lines starting `;` will also be eliminated (characteristic of `findstr`)

Comment: @jyao Your assertion about the syntax of the redirected-echo is completely wrong however. It does not matter whether the redirection appears before or after the `echo` and the space before the `>>` will be reproduced so each output line will be terminated by an extra space. Actually, this is the reason for using the unconventional redirection-before-echo structure.

Comment: I guess my assertion about the syntax is indeed not right because when I did the test, I used @echo (trying to prevent displaying echo), without using `@`, your command indeed works. My apology.

Answer (score 1):

I suggest tail to output lines starting with line number 2:

```
tail -n +2 in.txt > out.txt
```

From the man page:

```
       -n, --lines=[+]NUM
          output the last NUM lines, instead of the last  10;  or  use  -n
          +NUM to output starting with line NUM
```

Comment: This seems to be a bash command, but original question seems to be related to a DOS CMD

Answer (score 0):

This is pretty easy with PowerShell. If the file is not large, `Get-Content` works well.

```
Get-Content -Path .\t.txt | Select-Object -Skip 1
```

If you must run from a cmd.exe shell, then use:

```
powershell -NoProfile -Command "Get-Content -Path .\t.txt | Select-Object -Skip 1"
```

Answer (score 0):

If you like using Vim with CMD you can use: `gvim -c "execute \"normal! #dd\"" file.txt`, where "#" is the number of lines you want to delete off of the top of the text file ("#" could "1", "82", or another number). For this question you want `gvim -c "execute \"normal! 1dd\"" file.txt`.

Answer (score 0):

: Execute the command WMIC and remove the first line and the last blank line.  This can
: be easily modified to work on a file too. I just needed a viable replacement for
: the older "NET VIEW" command.

for /f "skip=1 delims=$" %f in ('"wmic /NAMESPACE:\root\directory\ldap PATH ds_computer GET ds_samaccountname "') do @for /f %g in ("%f") do @echo \%g